# Working with expected value of a matrix

Tags: mathematical-statistics, expected-value, matrix

If I have two matrices $C$ and $D$ of the same size.

If I know that the expected value of $C$, denoted by $E(C)$, is equal to $D$. So $E(C)=D$.

In this case, $E(diag(C))$ will be equal to $diag(D)$, so that $E(diag(C)) = diag(D)$ where $diag$ denotes a diagonal matrix. But what about $E(diag^2(C))$?? does the latter can be equal to $diag^2(D)$??

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: If by $diag(C)$ you mean a diagonal matrix whose diagonal is the same as the diagonal of $C$ and $diag^2(C)$ means $(diag(C))^2$, a diagonal matrix whose entries are the squares of the entries of $diag(C)$, then your question boils down to asking whether for a random variable $X$, $E[X^2]$ can possibly equal $(E[X])^2$. This simpler question has an answer that you ought to know.  Hint: contemplate the equation $$var(X) = E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So in this case, can we express $E(diag^2(C)) = E(diag(C) * diag(C)) = cov(diag(C), diag(C)) + E(diag(C))E(diag(C))$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by expected value of a matrix $E[C]=D$ you mean the matrix $D$ whose elements are equal to expected values of elements of matrix $C$.

Assuming that you mean $diag^2(C)\equiv diag(C)diag(C)$ you have the diagonal matrix under the expectation whose elements are equal to squares of diagonal elements of $C$. In this case you know that $E[C_{ii}^2]\ne E[C_{ii}]^2$. Therefore the answer is NO, $E[C_{ii}^2]\ne diag^2(D)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So in this case, can we express $E(diag^2(C)) = E(diag(C) * diag(C)) = cov(diag(C), diag(C)) + E(diag(C))E(diag(C))$ ?

Comment: Yes, but make sure you're clear with definitions of expectation of the matrix and with the square of the diagonal.

Comment: What is meant by $cov(diag(C),diag(C))$? A _$n$-vector_ random variable has a $n\times n$ covariance matrix, a **$n\times n$ matrix** of random variables (effectively a vector of $n^2$ random variables) has a $n^2\times n^2$ covariance matrix. This whole question has so much unnecessary irrelevant baggage in it that it is hard to figure out what exactly is being asked.

Comment: I just applied the formula: "cov(a,b) = E(ab) - E(a)E(b)". this is not correct? Kindly I need your help :)

Comment: @DilipSarwate, the product of diagonal matrices will produce diagonal matrix, no cross-terms

Comment: @Aksakal and since the diagonal has $n$ random variables in it, there are $n^2$ covariances that must be specified. What are these covariance values? What do _you_ mean by $cov(diag(C),diag(C))$ when you agree with Christina's formula in her comments?

Comment: @DilipSarwate, no. She means a diagonal *matrix* by $diag()$. When you square it, you'll get a diagonal matrix again, which has no cross-terms, they're simple squares of the diagonal elements

Answer (score 2):

Nope.

Think of it like this: if $diag(C)$ has sometimes positive, sometimes negative values, but always <> 0, it's $E(diag(C))$ can (let's imagine one such case) be equal to 0, when you do the averaging over all samples.

But when you square $diag(C)$ - it's $E(diag^2(C))$ will always be >= 0, while $diag^2(D)$ will remain == 0.

Hope that helped.